# mac os x python/JavaScript IDE where I can use break points

Tags: javascript, python, macos, ide

I looking for python/JavaScript IDE where I can put breakpoints. Currently I'm using coderunner but I can not put break points. I'll really appreciate you recommendations

Comment: I use Google Chrome for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Python, but I do work as a web developer and use JavaScript regularly. For that side of things, probably the easiest way is to use Chrome/Firefox debugger tools. You can do this manually by finding the line of code in the console and clicking (F12->Sources tab->Content scripts->*desired script*), or using the 'debugger' statement to toggle debug mode (F12->Console tab->type 'debugger' then return) and step through to what you need.

Additionally, if you're looking for an actual IDE, the only thing I've found online is [the following](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/05/the-three-ways-of-setting-breakpoints-in-javascript/). Here's the relevant part of that article. I've never used it (and probably never will), but there it is all the same.

> Webstorm by IDEA supports setting breakpoints in the IDE. This requires launching the JavaScript debugger from IDEA. It must be configured in advance so it understands how to map JavaScript on the development server to JavaScript files in your environment. IDEA will automatically install a Chrome or Firefox plug-in to facilitate. This is pretty new technology and can be touchy.
>
> [image: cited image]

Answer (score 0):

I use PyCharm.  It's a heavyweight IDE, so expect more features than you probably want if you're just getting started.  It has a very good integrated debugger.  You'll be able to break into both your Python and Javascript.  Further, you'll see a pretty nice productivity jump with all the editing support like auto complete and intellisense.  My advice is to stick with print() and logging as long as you can. For me getting a firm grasp of packages, python environments, virtualenv, command line tricks and git all before committing to the PyCharm IDE helped me adopt it with more confidence I was getting the value of all the integration.

Comment: +1 for PyCharm. Been a licensed pro user for about 3 years, its integration is one of the better offerings (although, not without its own caveats). PyDev for eclipse has turned into a real beast with the forced integration of all the Aptana crap on top of it.. It's almost unusable to me but probably the second on my list.